# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function error showing in a @Composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having problems with the `@Composable` annotation. I am in a `@Composable` function, but it shows an error here:

```
Column {
    Text(
        text = "Rutinas",
        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 28.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
```

I guess it is because i am changing the context when doing `.let`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Full code:

```
@Composable
fun RutinaList(
    rutinasViewModel: RutinasViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = RutinasViewModelFactory(
            RutinasRepository()
        )
    )
) {
    val rutinasList = rutinasViewModel.getRutinasInfo().collectAsState(initial = null).value
    val listOfRutinas = rutinasList.querySnapshot?.toObjects(Rutina::class.java)
    listOfRutinas?.let { rutina ->
        Column {
            Text(
                text = "Rutinas",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 28.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            )

            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                items(listOfRutinas) {
                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        RutinaDetails(rutina)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually `?.let` approach works fine to me, it's hard to say what's the problem in your case without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try specifying classes for the variables and replacing view model call  with static values, this may highlight the real problem.

Comment: listOfRutinas is clearly not a composable. The Column composable has to run inside another composable.

Comment: @AndroidDev that's not true, changing scope doesn't ruin Composable scope, see [this sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/beadd8872e5b9e953ad9f59b3ffe44f2) which runs fine. Same you can use `Collection.forEach`, etc. Only especially marked scopes can forbid Compose calls, like `LazyColumn` does

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I'm assuming that toObjects is just an object. forEach is not an object and therefore you can place composables inside of it. But if toObject is just an object, you cannot do that.

Comment: Composable invocations can be forbidden if the lambda is a side effect. Thanks to `contract callsInPlace` `let` is guarantied to be called during invocation, without a side effect, that's why it doesn't ruin Composable scope.